Adding ZOrder to JLabels causes them to Flicker in Jframe
I am trying to make a 2D game using Java Swing, but I am running into some trouble. I added ZOrder to my JLabels because I wanted them to appear in a certain order, but it caused them to start flickering, I am new to using Java GUI so I'm not too sure what's going on. Here is the code that I wrote:
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.Clock;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class World implements KeyListener {
    // Creates world.
    protected JFrame console = new JFrame("Tower of Fiction");
    // Keeps track of all objects in the world.
    protected ArrayList<JLabel> displayObjects = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    // A timer used to delay actions.
    protected Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    // Used to track menu button choice
    protected int menuOption = 0;
    // To close game.
    private boolean close = false;
    // For screen 2 activation.
    private boolean screen2 = false;
    private int ticker2 = 21;
    private long delay2 = 0;
 
    public World() throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        // Creates a game console using JFrame.
        console.setSize(1920, 1080);
        console.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        console.setLayout(null);
        console.addKeyListener(this);
        drawText("Start Game", "BLKCHCRY.TTF", 100f, 201, 193, 59, 750, 440, 1);
        drawText("Settings", "BLKCHCRY.TTF", 100f, 201, 193, 59, 828, 605, 1);
        displayObjects.get(1).setVisible(false);
        drawText("Quit Game", "BLKCHCRY.TTF", 100f, 201, 193, 59, 762, 775, 1);
        displayObjects.get(2).setVisible(false);
        drawImage("Animations and Images/Images/PNG/Fictionville Home Screen (First Time).png", 0, 0, 1);
        console.setVisible(true);
 
        while (close == false) {
            if (screen2 == true) {
                 
                if (delay2 < clock.millis()) {
                     
                    drawImage("Animations and Images/Animations/GIF/Load Screen Animation/Loading Screen" + ticker2
                            + ".png", 0, 0, 0);
                    delay2 = clock.millis() + 100;
                    ticker2--;
                    
 
                    if (ticker2 == 0) {
 
                        screen2 = false;
                    }
                }
            }
 
            console.revalidate();
            console.repaint();
        }
    }
 
    // Adding an image to console.
    public void drawImage(BufferedImage image, int xCord, int yCord, int order) {
        JLabel asset = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        Dimension size = asset.getPreferredSize();
        asset.setBounds(xCord, yCord, size.width, size.height);
        console.add(asset);
        console.setComponentZOrder(asset, order);
        displayObjects.add(asset);
    }
 
    // Adding an image to console using file path.
    public void drawImage(String imagePath, int xCord, int yCord, int order) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
        drawImage(image, xCord, yCord, order);
    }
 
    // Draw text on screen.
    public void drawText(String text, String fontPath, float size, int R, int G, int B, int xCord, int yCord, int order)
            throws FontFormatException, IOException {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        Font fontStyle = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream(fontPath)).deriveFont(size);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(fontStyle);
 
        label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(R, G, B));
        label.setFont(fontStyle);
 
        Dimension sizeOfWords = label.getPreferredSize();
        label.setBounds(xCord, yCord, sizeOfWords.width, sizeOfWords.height);
    
        console.add(label);
        console.setComponentZOrder(label, order);
        label.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        displayObjects.add(label);
    }
 
    // Clears all images on console.
    public void clear() {
        console.getContentPane().removeAll();
    }
 
    // For resizing images.
    public BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage image, int width, int length) {
        return toBufferedImage(image.getScaledInstance(width, length, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    }
 
    public BufferedImage resizeImage(String imagePath, int width, int length) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
        return toBufferedImage(image.getScaledInstance(width, length, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    }
 
    private static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img) {
        if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
            return (BufferedImage) img;
        }
 
        // Create a buffered image with transparency
        BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
 
        // Draw the image on to the buffered image
        Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
        bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        bGr.dispose();
 
        // Return the buffered image
        return bimage;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
 
        if (screen2 == false) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                if (menuOption == 2) {
                    displayObjects.get(menuOption).setVisible(false);
                    menuOption = 0;
                }
 
                else {
                    displayObjects.get(menuOption).setVisible(false);
                    menuOption++;
                }
 
                displayObjects.get(menuOption).setVisible(true);
            }
 
            else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                if (menuOption == 0) {
                    displayObjects.get(menuOption).setVisible(false);
                    menuOption = 2;
                }
 
                else {
                    displayObjects.get(menuOption).setVisible(false);
                    menuOption--;
                }
 
                displayObjects.get(menuOption).setVisible(true);
            }
 
            if (menuOption == 2 && keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                close = true;
                console.dispose();
            }
        }
 
        if (menuOption == 0 && keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || menuOption == 0 && keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            screen2 = true;
        }
    }
 
    // Called when a key is released
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // Handle key release if needed
    }
 
    // Called when a key is typed (pressed and released)
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Handle key typing if needed
    }



We don't have access to your images so we can't run the code. 2) We don't have access to your fonts so we can't run the code. Create an [mre] demonstrating the problem. Use standard Fon'ts. Use Text to represent the images of your labels. 3) Swing components are double buffered by default, so there is no need for the setDoubleBuffered(...) method.



Updates to Swing components must be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) so use a Swing Timer for the animation. Read the Swing Tutorial there are section on "Concurrency" and "Using Swing Timers".  Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use KeyBindings. Tutorial also has a section on key bindings. 5) Images should probably be read at the start of the class so you don't continually read them or have delays reading them. 6) Don't continually create a new JLabels. Just change the Icon of the existing label.


Hi, this is very informative! I have managed to fix the error I was having by having the images initialized at the beginning rather then during the while loop. I also used image icons to change the label instead as u said and am currently adding the swing timer, im hoping this will fix the choppy animation that I am getting when I repaint
